# Hair Shape in Eevee

Tags: particles, hair, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to make a Christmas Tree in Blender 2.8 using the new Eevee Render Engine, I used a Particle System to make the little green pines.

In the Cycles Render Engine I could change the thickness of the Hair using the Hair Shape option, but these settings don't seem to work in Eevee.

Is there any other way to change the thickness of the Hair? Or do I have to use Cycles and wait until Eevee adds these features?

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the *Render* properties window you must set the ***Hair Shape Type*** to ***Strip***.

Once you do that, the *Hair Shape* properties will affect the EEVEE result as expected.

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly, that requires version 2.87 or newer.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen Blender 2.87 has never existed. This configuration requires Blender 2.80 or newer (with Blender 2.79 you wouldn't have EEVEE at all)